# Install php7.0-pgsql inside docker php:7.0-apache

Tags: docker

I try to install php7.0-pgsql inside my php:7.0-apache image.
I know there are a lot of comparable issues on the internet but I really need help for this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales locales-all && \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install php7.0-pgsql
COPY src/ /var/www/html
```

The following error appears during my docker build:

```
# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmppxe6egn8/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmppxe6egn8/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmppxe6egn8/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [549 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages

Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [17.8 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9063 kB]
Fetched 9630 kB in 11s (870 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update &&     apt-get -y install software-properties-common locales locales-all &&     LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php &&     apt-get -y update &&     apt-get -y install php7.0-pgsql' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: If you look at the Dockerfile for `php:7.0-apache` https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/2630167f7e69394bdd91f240443a0a521fd7872d/7.0/apache/Dockerfile. It inherits from `debian:jessie`, your PPA is for ubuntu and not `debian:jessie`. So find the right PPA for debian and then try

Comment: Any comments to my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an excerpt from a `Dockerfile` I am using

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I am compiling the extensions myself since the PHP within the official images is also compiled from source and not taken from the Debian repository.